# Word not preceded by a regular expression

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

There are plenty of these questions but they all focus on having a couple of characters.

In a text file i have TXX and txx and i need to find those. But I also have Base64 encoded pictures.

Meaning I have

> "picture":"/9j/4AAQSkTXX . . .

Basically `TXX`, `txx` can appear randomly in Base64-encoded pictures.

I used the following regular expression:

```
(?<!"picture":")(?:(\w|\/|\+)+)(TXX|txx)
```

I also realized it should probably be changed into:

```
(?<!"picture":")(?:(\d|\w|\/|\+|\=)+)(TXX|txx)
```

But it says I'm doing a catastrophic backtracking, and even without the `(?:)` (non-capturing group) it still doesn't work. Basically it just doesn't take the "picture":" and the first char and takes everything else.

Since I cannot put a regular expression inside the negative look-behind with a quantifier like

```
(?<!"picture":".+)TXX|txx
```

How should I form that regular expression so that these pass

```
"something-txx": "somerandomstring"
value not picture:  "some other stringtxxsome string"
```

But this doesn't

```
"picture":"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"
```

Sample input is on : 
http://pastebin.com/5XJVNqGS 
(I know pastebin is bad since the expiration but i'm having problem pasting that amount of text as the page stucks)

And the results should be:

> Result1: "some-txx": value
>
> Result2: hereisTXX: "1235"
>
> Result3: "GROUPDATA" : "{DATA1: sample, TXX-value:12312 ,DATA2: sample2}"

Comment: Get a JSON parser, then work on the data. You might want to decode base64 the data and locate the exact bytes - to prevent excluding the wrong data.

Comment: Please show a CLEAR sample input and your desired output.

Comment: I can provide a sample input and desired output but that is just that - a sample. I need a basic case.
Will attach sample in original post in just a moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use a rather useful Java "to-some-extent" variable-width look-behind:

```
(?<!"picture":"[^"]{0,10000})(?i:txx)
```

You can adjust the `10000` value in case you have longer Base64-encoded strings.

Tested on [RegexPlanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/cookbook/ahJzfnJlZ2V4cGxhbmV0LWhyZHNyDwsSBlJlY2lwZRjKtIETDA/index.html)

In case you have very large images, use a reverse-string trick with a reversed regex (look-aheads can be of undefined variable size):

```
String rx = "(?i)\"[^\"]*\"\\s*:\\s*\"[^\"]*xxt[^\"]*\"(?![^\"]*\":\"erutcip\")";
```

Sample [Java program on Ideone](https://ideone.com/ckLiPL):

```
import java.util.regex.*;
class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){

     String str = "THE_HUIGE_STRING_THAT_CAUSED_Body is limited to 30000 characters;you entered 53501_ISSUE";
     str = new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString();
     String rx = "\"?[^\"]*\"?\\s*\"?[^\"\\n\\r]*(?:xxt|XXT)[^\"\\n\\r]*(?![^\"]*\":\"erutcip\")";
     Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile(rx);
     Matcher m = ptrn.matcher(str);
     while (m.find()) {
         System.out.println(new StringBuilder(m.group(0)).reverse().toString());
     }

     m = ptrn.matcher(new StringBuilder("\"something-txx\": \"somerandomstring\"").reverse().toString());
     while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(new StringBuilder(m.group(0)).reverse().toString());
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah that doesn't really work for me since i don't know the length of the Base64 encoded string prior to execution :/

Also i get the following error
`{0,1000} Lookbehinds need to be zero-width, thus quantifiers are not allowed` 
And for 1000000 it just says quantifier is too large.

Comment: But how big are those images? 10MB? I doubt they can be more than 20MB. Then, try with `(?<!"picture":"[^"]{0,20000000})(?i:txx)`. Or you will need to use a reverse-string trick.

Comment: I see, unfortunately, RegexPlanet did not warn of this. Java does support a `{}` quantifier in a look-behind with set min and max parameters, but I did not know about the actual limit on the max parameter. So, you can only use the reverse string trick. It is strange, at http://goo.gl/DZxwnX the regex compiles well :(

Comment: The reverse string trick will work almost certainly, my files are about 20 megs but reversing it shouldn't be a problem line by line. Very smart solution and so simple ! :)

Comment: @daniels_pa: Please check my suggested solution and the code on Ideone. No `txx` is returned if there is `picture` in front.

Comment: `String str = "\"picture\":\"iVBORw0KGgotxxAT0yaNTMFf\"";
     str+="\n\"some-txx\": value\nhereisTXX: \"1235\"\n\"GROUPDATA\" : \"{DATA1: sample, TXX-value:12312 ,DATA2: sample2}\"";
     str = new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString();
     String rx = "(?i)\"[^\"]*\"\\s*:\\s*\"[^\"]*xxt[^\"]*\"(?![^\"]*\":\"erutcip\")";
     Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile(rx);
     Matcher m = ptrn.matcher(str);
     while (m.find()) {
         System.out.println(new StringBuilder(m.group(0)).reverse().toString());
     }`

     Here is the chunk of code. Doesn't return nothing :/

Comment: I tried that code , but the end of the code i didn't need (with something-txx) since that was just an example of what can appear. So basically i need all the txx that don't apear as part of the picture :)

Comment: String rx = "\\s*\"?[^\"\\n\\r]*(xxt|XXT)[^\"\\n\\r]*(?![^\"]*\":\"erutcip\")";

I need something along this line basically i **need to capture** the rest of the txx,TXX **that are not part of the picture**
And the regex in the solution doesn't capture anything :) So if a picture is closed - we have a pair of " in the value part that means we can can continue searching for txx or TXX.

Comment: String rx = "\"?[^\"]*\"?\\s*\"?[^\"\\n\\r]*(xxt|XXT)[^\"\\n\\r]*(?![^\"]*\":\"erutcip\")";

Is the most aproximate thing to what i need , thanks :) This will most likely solve my problem :)

Comment: Great it finally worked for you. I onlu suggest using a non-capturing group with `(?:xxt|XXT)`, or even turn off case sensitivity to this group with `i`: `(?i:xxt)` if you want to also check for `xXt` or `xXT`.